# How can I prevent pixelated when I make smaller image with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

This following code is making smaller size of image using `UIGraphicsImageContext`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight), false, 1.0)
newImage.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

And I paste the image to `UIPasteboard`.
I tried setting scale value to 0.0 but in this case the image size doesn't change.

To help quick understanding I added this.
Following is screenshot of message edit box that have pasted images.

[image: Sample Image]

Above is pixelated image that made by code and below is original image.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Seeing a screenshot of what you see and what you expect might help.

Comment: "I tried setting scale value to 0.0 but in this case the image size doesn't change." You are not understanding what scale is. The image may measure 100x100 but if it is scale 2 it is treated as 50x50. Thus, setting the scale value to 0.0 is the right answer, because it gives you automatic correct scale for the current device. Provide real code with real value and real outcome within the iOS app (including how you are displaying the image), and I'll prove it to you.

Comment: Original Size : 180 x 180
Changed Size: 72 x 72
scale : 1.0
I put the `UIImage` to `UIPasteboard` by data. 
When I set scale to 0.0, the size changes a little.
Why this is happening, matt?